# Method overloading and inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, overloading

I have the following classes:

```
public class BaseRepository
{
    public virtual void Delete(int id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Delete by id in BaseRepository");
    }
}

public class EFRepository: BaseRepository
{
    public override void Delete(int id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Delete by Id in EFRepository");
    }

    public void Delete(object entity)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Delete by entity in EFRepository");
    }
}
```

Then I use it like:

```
var repository = new EFRepository();
int id = 1;
repository.Delete(id);
```

Why in that case only `EFRepository.Delete(object entity)` will call?

Comment: object can hold an int.

Comment: @TravisJ I know it well but the question was a little bit different

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Basically, the way method invocation works in C# is that the compiler looks at the most derived class first, and sees whether any *newly declared* methods (not including overrides) are applicable for the arguments for the call. If there's at least one applicable method, overload resolution works out which is the best one. If there isn't, it tries the base class, and so on.

I agree this is surprising - it's an attempt to counter the "brittle base class" issue, but I would personally prefer that any *overridden* methods were included in the candidate set.

Method invocation is described in section 7.6.5.1 of the C# 5 specification. The relevant parts here is:

> - The set of candidate methods is reduced to contain only methods from the most derived types: For each method `C.F` in the set, where `C` is the type in which the method `F` is declared, all methods declared in a base type of `C` are removed from the set. Furthermore, if `C` is a class type other than object, all methods declared in an interface type are removed from the set. (This latter rule only has affect when the method group was the result of a member lookup on a type parameter having an effective base class other than object and a non-empty effective interface set.)

And in the member lookup part of 7.4, `override` methods are explicitly removed:

> Members that include an `override` modifier are excluded from the set.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So, there is no way to call the method with int parameter directly, right?

Comment: @MegaTron: You'd have to cast to BaseRepository first.

Comment: Thanks. I think it will be better to change that design

Comment: Does the phrase "newly declared methods (not just overridden ones)" exclude overridden methods?  If so, the "just" makes it confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Because: public override void Delete(int id) will **only override the base class method** which one : public virtual void Delete(int id).

While public void Delete(object entity) is the **EFRepository class method**, so when you execute method **from EFRepository object** it will **invoke to own method** which is nothing but the public void Delete(object entity)