# Different behaviour of overlaoded method call if method is overriden

Tags: c#, .net, class, oop, inheritance

I have two overloaded methods `MyMethod`. One with an `int` as parameter the other with a `long`.

Calling this method from outside with a integer calls the `MyMethod(int)` member. But if the method with `int` is overridden then the `MyMethod(long)` is called. I do not understand why dot.net behaves like this. Can someone explain the technical background?
For me it looks like a bug.

Example **1.** and **3.** (see code below) behaves like I would expect. But the **2.** one I cannot explain why the code calls the long method.

```
// 1. Normal Overloading

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int value = 123;
        new MyClass().MyMethod(value);

        // Output: Method INT

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod(int value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method INT");
    }

    public void MyMethod(long value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method LONG");
    }
}


// 2. Combine Overriding with Overloading

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int value = 123;
        new MyChildClass1().MyMethod(value);

        // Output: Method LONG

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class MyParentClass
{
    public virtual void MyMethod(int value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method INT");
    }
}
class MyChildClass1 : MyParentClass
{
    public override void MyMethod(int value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method INT");
    }

    public void MyMethod(long value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method LONG");
    }
}


// 3. Inherit but use New for overloading

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int value = 123;
        new MyChildClass2().MyMethod(value);

        // Output: Method INT

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class MyParentClass
{
    public virtual void MyMethod(int value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method INT");
    }
}
class MyChildClass2 : MyParentClass
{
    public new void MyMethod(int value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method INT");
    }

    public void MyMethod(long value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method LONG");
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method overloading and inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39233741/method-overloading-and-inheritance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a planned behavior (but I agree this is a bit of confusing especially in comparison with others examples). From [here](http://www.csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx):

> There's one aspect of this behaviour which is particularly surprising though. What counts as a method being "declared" in a class? It turns out that if you override a base class method in a child class, that doesn't count as declaring it.